# Prove the subsequence of all zeros converges to zero

Tags: real-analysis

> "Does there exist a sequence that is unbounded, but has a convergent subsequence? If not, then provide a proof. If yes, give an example and prove your claim."

I know that an unbounded sequence can still have convergent subsequences for example, the sequence $x_n=(1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0,…)$ is unbounded but its subsequence $x_{2k}=(0, 0, 0,..)$ is convergent but I don't know how to prove using the definition of a limit that it converges to 0.

This is what I get when I try to use the definition of the limit:

Let ε > 0 and let natural number N = 1 then for all natural number n ≥ N, |0 - 0|= 0 < ε. Therefore the subsequence x_2k converges to 0.

This proof feels like I just restated the definition of the limit and I didn't do anything.

Also it would be great if anyone knows of more examples of convergent subsequences of unbounded sequences that is better than my example!

Comment: Your example is perfectly good.  There is no "better" example. Do you know the definition of the limit of a sequence using $\varepsilon$ and $N$?  It's very easy to apply this to the sequence $(0,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: You're probably used to someone else giving you a sequence and having to prove the limit. But in this case you got to choose the sequence, and you chose very well - so well that proving the limit is so easy that it feels like you didn't do enough work. But it is actually that easy in this case, and you can feel content that you picked your sequence so well!

Comment: Okay thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Everything you did is right and it could be different, but not simpler. You could replace the 0 with $1/n$, but I think it's worse.
It feels like you have a hard time accepting the sequence 0,0,... converges to 0, maybe it's because you think converging is getting closer and closer (and you can't get closer than equaling) when it's getting arbitrary close to the limit.

Comment: (+1) The suggestion of replacing $0$ with $1/n$ is a nice immediate fix to the OP's question. (OP is an old Usenet abbreviation for "original poster", although I've noticed in recent years it sometimes is used to refer to the actual original question itself rather than to the questioneer.) And "*you can't get closer than equaling*" is a nice way of getting at the OP's uneasy feeling.

Answer (score 0):

I am just a student so I hope my answer is good.
From my point of view you are correct and more formally you can writte.

Let define the following sequence:
$x_n=\left\{\begin{matrix}
n \; iff \; n \; is \;  odd \\ 
0 \; iff \; n \; is \;  even
\end{matrix}\right.$
That means $x_n=(1;0;3;0;5;0;...)$

Now by definition.

1. $x_{2k} \underset{n \to \infty }{\rightarrow} 0$
   $\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists N=1 \; s.t. \; \forall k > N=1 \Rightarrow |x_{2k}-0|=|0-0|=0 < \epsilon$
2. $x_{2k-1} \underset{n \to \infty }{\rightarrow} \infty$
   $\forall M>0 ,\exists N=M+1 \; s.t. \; \forall k >N=M+1 \Rightarrow x_{2k-1}=2k-1>2(M+1)-1=2M+1>M$
   This allow you to conclude that $x_n$ is unbound as it exist a subsequence of $x_n$ going to infinity.
   *Rem:* Note that by def of the sequence $x_n$ we have that $x_{2k-1}=2k-1$